# shell script to quickly jump to a directory

Tags: shell, command-line

I am using mac.

When I do

```
p demo
```

on my terminal then I want to go to

```
cd /Users/dorelal/prod_demo
```

I tried adding following commands to my ~/.bashrc but none of them worked.

```
alias p='cd /Users/dorelal/prod_$1'

function p {
  cd '/Users/dorelal/prod_$1'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
p() {
  cd "/Users/dorelal/prod_$1"
}
```

Note the double quotes, rather than single quotes, to allow expansion of the `$1`.